# Convert matlab make from linux version to windows version

Tags: matlab, makefile

I have this linux makefile from public code and now I'm trying to use it on Windows
http://pastebin.com/gSqRFUvQ

This is what I have so far.
http://pastebin.com/iHugE5Z6

But I get an error on line 80.

```
    echo "#include \"../src/gconv.cu\"" > "matlab/mex/gconv.cpp"
    "/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Matlab2014b/bin/win64/mex"  -lmwblas -largeArrayDims "matlab/mex/gconv.cpp" matlab/src/bits/im2col.obj matlab/src/bits/pooling.obj matlab/src/bits/normalize.obj -o "matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64" 2> >(sed 's/^\(.*\)(\([0-9][0-9]*\)): \([ew].*\)/\1:\2: \3/g' >&2)
    Unknown MEX argument '-o'.
    Makefile:79: recipe for target 'matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64' failed
    make: *** [matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64] Error 127
```

Basically the argument -o doesn't exist. I'm sure what the author wanted by that parameter. But I think it should be -output since it will produce .mew64 file. If I change that into "-output", it gets error in the middle.

```
echo "#include \"../src/gconv.cu\"" > "matlab/mex/gconv.cpp"
"/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Matlab2014b/bin/win64/mex"  -lmwblas -largeArrayDims "matlab/mex/gconv.cpp" matlab/src/bits/im2col.obj matlab/src/bits/pooling.obj matlab/src/bits/normalize.obj -output "matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64" 2> >(sed 's/^\(.*\)(\([0-9][0-9]*\)): \([ew].*\)/\1:\2: \3/g' >&2)
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
gconv.cpp
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\src\bits/mexutils.h(132) : error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\src\bits/mexutils.h(147) : error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\mex\../src/gconv.cu(228) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\mex\../src/gconv.cu(381) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\mex\../src/gconv.cu(459) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
c:\cygwin64\home\denny\jaderberg-eccv2014_textspotting-dbe823e3c642\matconvnet\matlab\mex\../src/gconv.cu(481) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data


Makefile:79: recipe for target 'matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64' failed
make: *** [matlab/mex/gconv.mexw64] Error 127
```

Is it not possible to use this on windows? Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: When you're compiling MEX code, there is no `-o` flag, but there is an `-O` flag. `-O` (CAPITAL OH) stands for optimization.  Look at the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html.  Whatever C/C++ file has the `mexFunction` declaration, that is the entry point, and the MEX file will be named after that function.  There's also no need for the `-output` flag either.  Look at the different compilation examples.  At the bare minimum, all you need is `mex -O file.c`.  Try replacing all `-o` with `-O` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should be now able to use the same networks in newer MatConvNet versions as a Windows support was added (even though there are still some glitches in some configurations...).
Also the bugs which you are reporting here were fixed as well (at that time the code was not fixed for the MSC compiler).